# Is there a function in R to define periods of time (within a timeseries) where a condition is true

Tags: r, zoo

I'm looking to extract the periods of time where a conditional is true. I'm happy to use any packages in R to achieve this, but have provided the example below using `zoo`. What I am trying to do, is find the 2 periods in this time series, where the value is greater than `4`.

```r
library(zoo)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'zoo'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     as.Date, as.Date.numeric

# Create an example timeseries
z = zoo(c(1:10, 10:1, 1:10, 10:1), 1:40)
z
#>  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 
#>  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  1  2  3  4  5  6 
#> 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 
#>  7  8  9 10 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1

# See the shape
plot(z)
```

[image]

```r
# Look for timepoints greater than 4
z > 4
#>     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13 
#> FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE 
#>    14    15    16    17    18    19    20    21    22    23    24    25    26 
#>  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE 
#>    27    28    29    30    31    32    33    34    35    36    37    38    39 
#>  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE 
#>    40 
#> FALSE

# Now I want to define the perilds where the above is true

# Desired result
data.frame(period = 1:2, 
           period_start = c(5, 25), 
           period_end = c(16, 36))
#>   period period_start period_end
#> 1      1            5         16
#> 2      2           25         36
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Using `rle` of `base`.

```
f_period <- function(z, n) {

   z_o4 <- rle(as.numeric(z) > n)
   o4_loc <- which(z_o4$values)

   df <- NULL
   for(j in seq_along(o4_loc)) 
    df <- rbind(df, 
      c(j, sum(zz_o4$lengths[1:(o4_loc[j] -1)]+1), 
                     sum(zz_o4$length[1:o4_loc[j]])))

    df
}

f_period(z, 4)
```

> ```
>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
> [1,]    1    5   16
> [2,]    2   27   36
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a vectorised version using `rle`.

```
period_where <- function(x) {
  x <- rle(as.vector(x))
  lens <- x$lengths
  ends <- cumsum(lens)[x$values]
  starts <- ends - lens[x$values] + 1L
  data.frame(
    period = seq_along(starts), 
    period_start = starts, 
    period_end = ends
  )
}
```

Usage

```
> x <- zoo::zoo(c(1:10, 10:1, 1:10, 10:1), 1:40)
> period_where(x > 4)

  period period_start period_end
1      1            5         16
2      2           25         36
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(x = c(1:10, 10:1, 1:10, 10:1))
dt[, y := seq_len(.N)]

dt[, .(period_start = first(y), 
              period_end = last(y), 
              val = first(x > 4)), .(period = rleid(x > 4))] -> dt1

dt1[which(val)][, val := NULL][, period := seq_len(.N)][]

#   period period_start period_end
#1:      1            5         16
#2:      2           25         36
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rleid` from data.table to get a compact expression.  `L` is a list whose ith component is a 2 element vector consisting of the start and end time of the ith period.

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
ok <- z > 4
L <- tapply(time(z)[ok], rleid(ok)[ok], range)
```

`L` may be sufficient but if you really need a data.frame then:

```
setNames(data.frame(seq_along(L), do.call("rbind", L)), c("period", "start", "end"))
##   period start end
## 2      1     5  16
## 4      2    25  36

plot(z, type = "h", lwd = 3, col = ok+1)
junk <- lapply(L, lines, c(4, 4)) # horiz lines from start to end
```

[image: screenshot]